# Schedule SQL Jobs from Central Management Server

Tags: sql-server, maintenance, central-management-server

I've set up a Central Management Server on a SQL Server 2016 instance.  I'm able to manually run queries against multiple servers, but I want to be able to run automated maintenance scripts.

Is there a way to set up a single SQL Job that will run a script against ALL registered servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a separate way to control multi server jobs as described in the following link.
It is a shame that these were never integrated together by MS

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-master-job?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I agree Stephen. There are bits and pieces for multi-server handling but nothing that ties them together.